# How to display items of two different arraylists in same recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-music-player

I'm building a audio player and there is a fragment "My Files" in which phone's internal storage is queried for all the folders that contain audio files and are displayed. What I have done is in "My Files" fragment I display the folders(in recyclerView). And on clicking any item(folder) of this recyclerView, another activity starts(MyFilesSong.java) which displays the audio files of clicked folder.

What I want - I want the fragment "My Files" to display the folder(as it already does) and when I click any item(folders), the audio files should be loaded in the same fragment(I don't want another activity for this). I hope I'm clear.

PS: Two recyclerviews are used and both of them have arraylist of different types- "MyFiles" uses foldermodel while "Songs.java" uses songinfomodel

In the second gif(mine) clicking the item opens a new activity. But I want what is implemented in the first one. The fragment shows the folders and on clicking the folder the audio files are shown.

MyFiles.java :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_files_activity, container, false);



    recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_files);
    pathTextView= view.findViewById(R.id.myFilesPath);

    myList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);






    Songpath = SongPath();

    for(int i = 0; i<Songpath.size();i++) {

        Log.e("Paths: ", Songpath.get(i));

        file = new File(  Songpath.get(i) ) ;

        try {
            sforFolders = new FolderModel(file.getParentFile().getName(),file.getParentFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myList.add(sforFolders);



    }

    myFilesAdapter = new MyFilesAdapter(getContext(), new MyFilesAdapter.MyFilesItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void folderonclicklistener(FolderModel name, int position) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Folder Name: "+name.getFolderName()+" Position: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),MyFilesSongs.class);
            i.putExtra("parentPath",name.getFolderPath());
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(myFilesAdapter);
    myFilesAdapter.getFilesFolders(myList);
    myFilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();







    return view;
   }
```

MyFilesAdapter.java :

```
   public class MyFilesAdapterFinal extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFilesAdapterFinal.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<FolderModel> SongParentPath = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
itemClickListener listener;

public MyFilesAdapterFinal(ArrayList<FolderModel> songParentPath, Context context,itemClickListener listener) {
    SongParentPath = songParentPath;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public MyFilesAdapterFinal.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_myfiles,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyFilesAdapterFinal.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    FolderModel name = SongParentPath.get(position);

    holder.rowtext.setText(String.valueOf(name.getFolderName()));
    holder.bind(name,listener);





}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (SongParentPath==null)? 0 : SongParentPath.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView rowtext;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rowtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
    }

    public void bind(final FolderModel name, final itemClickListener listener) {

       itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               listener.onClick(name,getLayoutPosition());
           }
       });
    }
}

public interface itemClickListener{

    void onClick(FolderModel name, int position);
}
```

Songs.java: (activity which lists audio files):

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view6 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_activity, null);
    FrameLayout container6 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container6.addView(view6);



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    String parentPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("parentPath");

    SongList = displayFolderFiles(parentPath);



    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getApplicationContext(), SongList, new SongAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickListener(SongInfoModel song, int position) {




            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), song.getSongName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            BaseActivity.setsongText(song);
            BaseActivity.ButtonPause();
       //     playAudio(position);
            BaseActivity.slidingUpPanelCollapsed();





        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClickListener(final SongInfoModel song, final int position, View v) {



          //  AddToPlayListDialog(song, v);


        }


    });


    recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);

}
```

SongsAdapter.java :

```
       public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.SongHolder> {

ArrayList<SongInfoModel> SongList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
private RecyclerItemClickListener listener;








public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SongInfoModel> SongList, RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {

    this.context = context;
    this.SongList = SongList;
    this.listener = listener;

}




@Override
public SongAdapter.SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_song, parent, false);
    return new SongHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SongAdapter.SongHolder holder, final int position) {



         final SongInfoModel songInfoModel = SongList.get(position);


         holder.songName.setText(songInfoModel.SongName);
         holder.artistName.setText(songInfoModel.ArtistName);
         holder.duration.setText(String.valueOf(songInfoModel.duration));
         String duration = Utility.convertDuration(songInfoModel.getDuration());
         holder.duration.setText(duration);
         Picasso.with(context).load(songInfoModel.getAlbumIDArtwork()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(holder.iv_artwork);
         holder.bind(songInfoModel, listener);






}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return SongList.size();
}

public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    TextView songName;
    TextView artistName;
    TextView duration;
    private ImageView iv_artwork;



    public SongHolder(View itemView)    {

        super(itemView);
        songName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.SongName);
        artistName= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ArtistName);
        duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        iv_artwork = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_artwork);


    }

    public void bind(final SongInfoModel songInfoModel, final RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onClickListener(songInfoModel, getLayoutPosition());

            }
        });

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                listener.onLongClickListener(songInfoModel, getLayoutPosition(),view);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

}

public interface RecyclerItemClickListener{

    void onClickListener(SongInfoModel songInfoModel, int position);
    void onLongClickListener(SongInfoModel songInfoModel, int position, View view);
```

}

Comment: Make a fragment transaction to replace fragments instead of open a new activity on the clicklistener.

Comment: Can you give me the example in code?

Comment: Change your MyFilesSongs class as a fragment & replace existing fragment with new fragment in adpater class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the activity that host both recyclerviews you should add this :

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_change" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Since both of your fragments are just RecyclerViews you go with that as main container, in the activity (make sure that's an AppCompatActivity), you call this:

```
SupportFragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FolderListFragment fragment = new FolderListFragment(); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_change, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And from the foldersAdapter you should go with this, instead of calling the activity:

```
SupportFragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FilesListFragment fragment = new FilesListFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("parentPath",name.getFolderPath());
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_change, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And the activity that holds the RecyclerView with the files have to  extends Fragment.

On the OnCreate of the Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        int myInt = bundle.getString("parentPath", defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Actually the MainActivity.java hosts the fragment "MyFiles" and Songs.java is an independent activity like MainActivity.

Comment: MyFiles is a fragment whereas Songs.java is an activity

Comment: And as you see in the first GIF, all the fragments are in viewpager(tablayout)

Comment: I implemented what you explained here. It was partially successful. Problem is both the  layout overlap each other.

Comment: @Rektirino what do you mean with the layouts overlap each other?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use Expandable Recycler View as a solution. Here is a link

[Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

If you have any problem regarding implementation of the Expandable Recycler View, dont hesitate to ask I will help 
I hope this helps ;)

Comment: No, I know what Expandable Recycler View does. Read my question again

Comment: Oh i see sorry mate;) I think you may use another fragment to show the list of audios (or list Of Whatever Model You Have) in the same activity just implement fragment if its okay i can help with that.

Comment: No problem, can you help me with the fragments though?

Comment: I think its not complicated i have reviewed your code tbh cant rewrite your code at this time but the simple way creating container in your current activity and two fragment that interact with each other passing the list of items that you wanna show

Comment: You may use Serializable or Parcelable interfaces for your model in order to pass a list of your model